# Avro multiple enum int the same type (avro.SchemaParseException: Can't redefine)

Tags: parsing, enums, compiler-errors, avro

A have the following avro schema, but if I want to parse it, then I got the following error:
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Can't redefine: ...

```
{
    "name": "card_1_nr",
    "type": "string"
}, {
    "name": "card_1_type",
    "type": {
        "name": "card_type",
        "type": "enum",
        "symbols": ["diamonds", "clubs", "hearts", "spades"],
        "default": "diamonds"
    }
}, {
    "name": "card_2_nr",
    "type": "string"
}, {
    "name": "card_2_type",
    "type": {
        "name": "card_type",
        "type": "enum",
        "symbols": ["diamonds", "clubs", "hearts", "spades"],
        "default": "diamonds"
    }
}
```

Comment: I found this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48100575/avro-multiple-record-of-same-type-in-single-schema), but its not working for types

Answer (score 0):

Just simply need to use the enume type name:

```
{
    "name": "card_1_nr",
    "type": "string"
}, {
    "name": "card_1_type",
    "type": {
        "name": "card_type",
        "type": "enum",
        "symbols": ["diamonds", "clubs", "hearts", "spades"],
        "default": "diamonds"
    }
}, {
    "name": "card_2_nr",
    "type": "string"
}, {
    "name": "card_2_type",
    "type": "card_type"
}
```